# How do I return a reference to something inside a RefCell without breaking encapsulation?

Tags: rust, encapsulation, contravariance, mutability, interior-mutability

I have a struct that has inner mutability.

```
use std::cell::RefCell;

struct MutableInterior {
    hide_me: i32,
    vec: Vec<i32>,
}
struct Foo {
    //although not used in this particular snippet,
    //the motivating problem uses interior mutability
    //via RefCell.
    interior: RefCell<MutableInterior>,
}

impl Foo {
    pub fn get_items(&self) -> &Vec<i32> {
        &self.interior.borrow().vec
    }
}

fn main() {
    let f = Foo {
        interior: RefCell::new(MutableInterior {
            vec: Vec::new(),
            hide_me: 2,
        }),
    };
    let borrowed_f = &f;
    let items = borrowed_f.get_items();
}
```

Produces the error:

```
error[E0597]: borrowed value does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:16:10
   |
16 |         &self.interior.borrow().vec
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ temporary value does not live long enough
17 |     }
   |     - temporary value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 15:5...
  --> src/main.rs:15:5
   |
15 | /     pub fn get_items(&self) -> &Vec<i32> {
16 | |         &self.interior.borrow().vec
17 | |     }
   | |_____^
```

The problem is that I can't have a function on `Foo` that returns a borrowed `vec`, because the borrowed `vec` is only valid for the lifetime of the `Ref`, but the `Ref` goes out of scope immediately.

I think the `Ref` must stick around [because](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html):

> `RefCell<T>` uses Rust's lifetimes to implement 'dynamic borrowing', a process whereby one can claim temporary, exclusive, mutable access to the inner value. Borrows for `RefCell<T>`s are tracked 'at runtime', unlike Rust's native reference types which are entirely tracked statically, at compile time. Because `RefCell<T>` borrows are dynamic it is possible to attempt to borrow a value that is already mutably borrowed; when this happens it results in task panic.

Now I could instead write a function like this that returns the entire interior:

```
pub fn get_mutable_interior(&self) -> std::cell::Ref<MutableInterior>;
```

However this potentially exposes fields (`MutableInterior.hide_me` in this example) that are really private implementation details to `Foo`.

Ideally I just want to expose the `vec` itself, potentially with a guard to implement the dynamic borrowing behavior. Then callers do not have to find out about `hide_me`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can create a new struct similar to the `Ref<'a,T>` guard returned by `RefCell::borrow()`, in order to wrap this `Ref` and avoid having it going out of scope, like this:

```
use std::cell::Ref;

struct FooGuard<'a> {
    guard: Ref<'a, MutableInterior>,
}
```

then, you can implement the `Deref` trait for it, so that it can be used as if it was a `&Vec<i32>`:

```
use std::ops::Deref;

impl<'b> Deref for FooGuard<'b> {
    type Target = Vec<i32>;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Vec<i32> {
        &self.guard.vec
    }
}
```

after that, update your `get_items()` method to return a `FooGuard` instance:

```
impl Foo {
    pub fn get_items(&self) -> FooGuard {
        FooGuard {
            guard: self.interior.borrow(),
        }
    }
}
```

and `Deref` does the magic:

```
fn main() {
    let f = Foo {
        interior: RefCell::new(MutableInterior {
            vec: Vec::new(),
            hide_me: 2,
        }),
    };
    let borrowed_f = &f;
    let items = borrowed_f.get_items();
    let v: &Vec<i32> = &items;
}
```

Comment: Is this the only/idiomatic way to do this? Seems like a bit of trouble... Though I suppose instead of a getItems() method, you could borrow the internals in a block directly where it would then go out of scope (or something...)

Comment: @Norcalli In the specific case of `RefCell`, the object needs to be notified when the reference goes out of scope (that's what the destructor of `Ref` does). Here, we need to preserve this behavior (the error of the OP was due to the `Ref` instance being dropped too early), and thus encapsulate it.

Answer (score 48):

Instead of creating a brand new type, you can use [`Ref::map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/cell/struct.Ref.html#method.map) (since Rust 1.8). This has the same result as [Levans' existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29401865/155423):

```
use std::cell::Ref;

impl Foo {
    pub fn get_items(&self) -> Ref<'_, Vec<i32>> {
        Ref::map(self.interior.borrow(), |mi| &mi.vec)
    }
}
```

You can also use new features like `impl Trait` to hide the `Ref` from the API:

```
use std::cell::Ref;
use std::ops::Deref;

impl Foo {
    pub fn get_items(&self) -> impl Deref<Target = Vec<i32>> + '_ {
        Ref::map(self.interior.borrow(), |mi| &mi.vec)
    }
}
```

Comment: What about instead of get_item, if you were implementing the std::ops::Index<> trait, which requires you to return &Self::Output .  Returning a std::cell::Ref, as far as I have been able to figure out, won't satisfy the trait requirement.  Is there a way to do interior mutability with for that trait?

Comment: Actually I found a way to do it with UnsafeCell, so I think maybe that will be good enough.

Comment: @DanielV [Implementing Index trait to return a value that is not a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39113649/155423). I wouldn't trust the `UnsafeCell` implementation because it's quite likely that it introduces memory unsafety.

Comment: Note: `map` doesn't exist for `Mutex` meaning that this kind of thing is single-thread only (and from glancing at the code in both `cell.rs` and `mutex.rs` I think `MutexGuard` at a minimum would need to be redesigned to support such).  I _think_ that it's possible to use a variant of @Levan's solution below in that case, but haven't tried it.

Answer (score 5):

You can wrap the `Vec` in an `Rc`.

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

struct MutableInterior {
    hide_me: i32,
    vec: Rc<Vec<i32>>,
}
struct Foo {
    interior: RefCell<MutableInterior>,
}

impl Foo {
    pub fn get_items(&self) -> Rc<Vec<i32>> {
        self.interior.borrow().vec.clone() // clones the Rc, not the Vec
    }
}

fn main() {
    let f = Foo {
        interior: RefCell::new(MutableInterior {
            vec: Rc::new(Vec::new()),
            hide_me: 2,
        }),
    };
    let borrowed_f = &f;
    let items = borrowed_f.get_items();
}
```

When you need to mutate the `Vec`, use [`Rc::make_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.make_mut) to obtain a mutable reference to the `Vec`. If there are still other `Rc`s referring to the `Vec`, `make_mut` will dissociate the `Rc` from the other `Rc`s, clone the `Vec` and update itself to refer to that new `Vec`, then give you a mutable reference to it. This ensures that the value in the other `Rc`s doesn't suddenly change (because `Rc` by itself doesn't provide interior mutability).

Answer (score 1):

`Ref<X>` is the usual answer.
However, sometimes, such as when designing a **`trait`**, a consistent interface is required. For instance a trait with:

```
fn get_x(&self) -> &X
```

will preclude structs storing `x` in a `RefCell<X>`, while:

```
fn get_x(&self) -> Ref<X>
```

will preclude structs storing `x` as a plain `X`.

A pattern that can be used to get around this is to instead take a method which operates on the data.

```
fn with_x(&self, fun : &dyn FnOnce(&X));
```

Which works with both classes using `X` *and* `RefCell<X>` (or any other composition for that matter):

```
fun(&self.x);
// or
fun(&self.x.borrow());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really **must** return a reference to the data (as in an external crate requires some interface or similar) you can do so with [`Rc::leak`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Ref.html#method.leak), which currently requires `nightly`, until it stabilizes you can help yourself with this little function:

```rust
use std::cell::Ref;
fn leak_ref<'a, T>(orig: Ref<'a, T>) -> &'a T {
    Box::leak(Box::new(orig))
}
```

The same disclaimer as for the original `leak` applies here to:

> The underlying `RefCell` can never be mutably borrowed from again and will always appear already immutably borrowed. It is not a good idea to leak more than a constant number of references. The `RefCell` can be immutably borrowed again if only a smaller number of leaks have occurred in total.