# Implementing Index trait to return a value that is not a reference

Tags: indexing, rust

I have a simple struct that I would like to implement `Index` for, but as a newcomer to Rust I'm having a number of troubles with the borrow checker.  My struct is pretty simple, I'd like to have it store a start and step value, then when indexed by a `usize` it should return `start + idx * step`:

```
pub struct MyStruct {
    pub start: f64,
    pub step: f64,
}
```

My intuition is that I'd simply be able to take the signature of `Index` and plug in my types:

```
impl Index<usize> for MyStruct {
    type Output = f64;

    fn index(&self, idx: usize) -> &f64 {
        self.start + (idx as f64) * self.step
    }
}
```

This gives the error `mismatched types` saying `expected type &f64, found type f64`.  As someone who has yet to fully understand how Rust's type system works, I tried simply slapping `&` on the expression:

```
fn index(&self, idx: usize) -> &f64 {
    &(self.start + (idx as f64) * self.step)
}
```

This now tells me that the `borrowed value does not live long enough`, so maybe it needs a lifetime variable?

```
fn index<'a>(&self, idx: usize) -> &'a f64 {
    &(self.start + (idx as f64) * self.step)
}
```

The error is the same, but the note now gives `lifetime 'a` instead of `lifetime #1`, so I guess that's not necessary, but at this point I feel like I'm stuck.  I'm confused that such a simple exercise for most languages has become so difficult to implement in Rust, since all I want to do is return a computation from a function that happens to be behind a reference.  How should I go about implementing `Index` for a simple structure where the value is calculated on demand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Index` trait is meant to return a borrowed pointer to a member of `self` (e.g. an item in a `Vec`). The signature of the `index` method from the `Index` trait makes it impractical to implement it to have the behavior you described, as you'd have to store every value returned by `index` in `self` and ensure that the pointers remain valid until the `MyStruct` is dropped.

Comment: So would it simply be better to implement a method on MyStruct called `index` or `at` that took a `usize` and returned a `f64`? I'd also like to implement the ability to index with the equivalent to a Python slice (`Range` I think in rust), is this possible with the `...` syntax as a function argument?

Comment: You can write a standalone `index` method, but you won't be able to use it with the indexing syntax (`x[i]`). Range syntax produces values with types provided by the standard library (e.g. `x..y` produces a [`Range`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/struct.Range.html) value).

Comment: So basically I'm just out of luck here?  Oh well, it isn't a huge deal, just a different paradigm to learn for a new language.

Answer (score -1):

This use case does not match the intuition for `Index`. When I see `myStruct[3]`, my intuition is that, just as for arrays, I'm getting a pointer to some already-initialized data. The interface for `Index` corroborates this intuition.

I can see two things that you might potentially be trying to achieve:

1. Getting nice indexing syntax for your datastructure.

In this case I would recommend against the premise of implementing `Index` and just provide a method that returns a `f64` instead of an `&f64` like so.

```
impl MyStruct {
    pub fn index(&self, idx: usize) -> f64 {
        self.start + (idx as f64) * self.step
    }
}
```

You don't get the operators, which is good because somebody reading `[]` would be mislead into thinking they were getting a pointer. But you do get the functionality you want. Depending on your use cases you may want to rename this method.

2. Passing `MyStruct` to a parameter with `Index` bounds.

This is trickier with good reason. `Index` expects the data to be there before it asks for it. You can't generate and return it because `index` returns `f64`, and you can't generate it in the datastructure and return a pointer because it doesn't take a `&mut self`. You'd have to populate these values before the call to `index`. Some redesign would be in order, and the direction of that redesign would depend on the larger context of your problem.

Comment: I think I see now that my intuition is different than what rust's conventions are.  This information is somewhat difficult to find, though, since rust is still a very young language.  My approach is basically your first suggestion, although I went with a trait that I named `At<Idx>` with a single method `at` that is modeled off of the design of `Index`.  I've already figured out how to make it automatically `At`-able with a `Range<Idx>` if the `impl` for `At<Idx>` exists, which is quite handy for Rust to be able to do.