# Sharing schema with struct children

Tags: indexing, reference, rust

I'm trying to implement a parser for a database file format.  Conceptually, I'm trying to define a struct like the following:

```
struct Database {
    schema: Vec<FieldDescriptors>,
    records: Vec<Record>,
}
```

`Record` is basically just a `Vec<u8>`.  In order to extract a column from a record, it needs to refer to a schema (to know which bytes to read).  I've tried to implement several designs unsuccessfully:

1) Have the `Record` struct store a reference to either the `Database` or the schema (stumbled on this answer: [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct), and I understand why it doesn't work).

2) Create different types for the record data (stored in the database struct), and a record that can actually return the appropriate columns(created on demand when needed).  A record contains a reference to the data, and a reference to the schema.  This worked fine, except that I want to be able to implement the `Index` trait to access a record.  Unfortunately, `index` must return a reference, so I can't return a new proxy object on demand.  (also apparently impossible to do currently [Implementing Index trait to return a value that is not a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39113649/implementing-index-trait-to-return-a-value-that-is-not-a-reference))

Other options I've considered: storing a copy of the schema with each record which would be wasteful, or storing the schema in a box and storing a reference to it in each record(seems the least onerous, but still unsatisfying).

Am I missing a good solution to this problem?

Comment: Use [`Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html)? Pass in a reference to a schema only when decoding, not as an attribute of the `Record`? Store the schema separately, don't bundle them? Use owning_ref?

Comment: RC seems like overkill since the schema lives exactly as long as the database.  I'd like to bundle them because I consider the schema to be a internal detail.  owning_ref looked like it might be what I want, but I'm a little confused how to use it.  I think I want to follow the RcRef for slices example from here, right?  https://kimundi.github.io/owning-ref-rs/owning_ref/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post very much code, but I imagine that you wanted to get the column information from the record using something like:

```
impl Record {
   fn get_column(&self, index: usize) -> Column {
       // use self.schema to get the column...
   }
}
```

A completely different design would be to associate this code with the the schema instead, and pass a `&Record` when you need the schema to do something on it. You can protect any user from having to deal with the schema directly by using a facade, which can be `Database` itself:

```
struct Schema {
   field_descriptors: Vec<FieldDescriptors>
}

struct Database {
    schema: Schema,
    records: Vec<Record>,
}

impl Schema {
    fn get_column(&self, record: &Record, index: usize) -> Column {
        // use self.field_descriptors to get the column...
    }
}

impl Database {
    fn get_column(&self, row: usize, col_index: usize) -> Column {
        schema.get_column(&self.records[row], col_index)
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't the user still need to objects in order to get a column out of a record?  I was hoping they could do something like `database[i].get_column(2)` .  Ideally the user doesn't have to concern themselves with the schema.

Comment: @BenJones If you access it through the `Database` struct then you can handle that extra argument so the user doesn't have to. I updated the code to include that.