# How can I make an indexable wrapper for both `Vec<i8>` and `&[i8]`?

Tags: rust, slice, traits, lifetime

Consider the following code:

```
use std::ops;

struct Wrap<T>(T);

impl<T> Wrap<T> {
    fn new(element: T) -> Self {
        Wrap(element)
    }
}

// implementation of other methods that makes the wrapper necessary ;-)

impl ops::Index<ops::Range<usize>> for Wrap<Vec<i8>> {
    type Output = Wrap<&[i8]>;

    fn index(&self, range: ops::Range<usize>) -> &Self::Output {
        &Wrap::<&[i8]>::new(&self.0[range])
    }
}

impl ops::Index<ops::Range<usize>> for Wrap<&[i8]> {
    type Output = Wrap<&[i8]>;

    fn index(&self, range: ops::Range<usize>) -> &Self::Output {
        &Wrap::<&[i8]>::new(&self.0[range])
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b735fb5dc8075a228f56d8e15d30e032&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

The compiler states:

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
  --> src/lib.rs:14:24
   |
14 |     type Output = Wrap<&[i8]>;
   |                        ^ expected lifetime parameter

error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
  --> src/lib.rs:21:45
   |
21 | impl ops::Index<ops::Range<usize>> for Wrap<&[i8]> {
   |                                             ^ expected lifetime parameter

error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
  --> src/lib.rs:22:24
   |
22 |     type Output = Wrap<&[i8]>;
   |                        ^ expected lifetime parameter
```

How should I set the lifetimes here? I want `Wrap` to work for owned `Vec`s as well as borrowed slices. What would be the best solution?

Comment: Vec already implement [`as_slice()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.as_slice) so I don't see the point. Do you need [`Cow<Vec<i8>>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html) ?

Comment: Yeah, I left out the parts that make the Wrapper necessary. I tried to focus the code on the problem. I know that there are other ways to implement this, but I think the best design would be a wrapper and feel this should be possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing Index trait to return a value that is not a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39113649/implementing-index-trait-to-return-a-value-that-is-not-a-reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That original design is not possible. [`Index`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html) expects the `index` method to return a reference to the value of type `Self::Output`:

```
fn index<'a>(&'a self, index: Idx) -> &'a Self::Output;
```

I expanded the lifetime above to emphasize that the returned value *must live for as long as `self` itself*. This is achievable when the referenced value is contained in the callee, but this is not the case for a wrapped value. In one of your attempts:

```
fn index<'a>(&'a self, range: ops::Range<usize>) -> &'a Self::Output {
    &Wrap::<&[i8]>::new(&self.0[range])
}
```

This creates a reference to a `Wrap` object that only lives locally (and so does not outlive `'a`). This case would call for a different trait, such as `WrapIndex`, which would, regretfully, not feature the same syntactic sugar. It also cannot be generalized much without generic associated types (GATs).

```
pub trait WrapIndex<Idx> where
    Idx: ?Sized, {
    type Output: ?Sized;
    fn wrap_index(&self, index: Idx) -> Wrap<&Self::Output>;
}
```

If you don't mind exposing all methods from a slice type into `Wrap`, you can also implement [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) for that wrapper, thus obtaining indexing and slicing for free.

```
impl<T> Deref for Wrap<T>
where T: Deref
{
    type Target = <T as Deref>::Target;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        self.0.deref()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Cow<[T]>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html) is probably what you are after:

> it can enclose and provide immutable access to borrowed data, and clone the data lazily when mutation or ownership is required

```
use std::borrow::Cow;

fn main() {
    let w1: Cow<[i8]> = vec![1i8, 2, 3].into();
    let w2: Cow<[i8]> = (&[1i8, 2, 3][..]).into();

    println!("{:?}", &w1[1..2]);
    println!("{:?}", &w2[1..2]);
}
```

This provides a wrapper applicable to both owned vectors and borrowed slices without the need to reinvent the wheel :).

Comment: `Cow` is a run-time checked wrapper. It does not seem to relate to the question at all.

Comment: @E_net4 there was no restriction on compile-time, no? That being said, I didn't think it incurs any runtime penalties; can you provide some reference? I'd like to know more.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. `Cow` is a good hint, but I really would like my own wrapper where I can implement own methods on. I left those out to focus the code on the problem.

Comment: Each time cow is written the struct need to check if it had clone the data or not.

Comment: To expand on the subject: [`Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html) is an enum. It contains either owned content or borrowed content, along with a discriminant value. This requires the program to check at run-time whether it is currently working with owned data or borrowed data.