# Returning errors from Index<> trait implementation - mismatched types

Tags: rust

I am attempting to implement the `Index` and `IndexMut` traits for a struct. The implementation for `Index` trait is as follows:

```
impl Index<Registers> for RegisterCollection {
    type Output = std::result::Result<i32, CpuError>;

    fn index(&self, index: Registers) -> &Self::Output {
        if !&self.registers.contains_key(&index) {
            return Err(CpuError::InvalidRegisterId);
        }

        Ok(self.registers[&index].get_value_ref())
    }
}
```

`registers` is a HashMap indexed by the register ID (from the `Registers` enum) to the `Register` struct. The details for which might just confuse things if I add them here. `get_value_ref()` returns a reference to the value field of the `Register` struct. This field is not public as the access is controlled by permissions, which could not be enforced if the field were public.

The error I am getting is as follows:

```
mismatched types
expected reference &std::result::Result<i32, cpu::CpuError>
    found enum std::result::Result<_, cpu::CpuError>
to return impl Trait, all returned values must be of the same type
```

This confuses me as it seems to be correct and what I have done here is similar to what I have done elsewhere. If anyone can explain what I'm doing wrong here and point me in the direction of how to fix it that would be most appreciated.

Comment: I belive [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39113649/1233251) answers your own, please have a look at the answers in it. Since `Index::index` may only return a reference, you cannot make it return a `Result` created in the function's scope like that.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem possible. If you look at the implementation of the Index trait for any of the stdlib collection types they all panic when a key is not present, none of them return Results. I recommend you panic on a missing key if you're determined to stick with using the Index trait, otherwise write your own trait which returns a Result instead of a &Result.

Comment: @E_net4 feels targeted I believe that you are correct. I did search the suggestions but that wasn't one of them. Cheers.