# Abstracting indexes in rust

Tags: arrays, rust, indexing, abstraction

I want a trait that is an indexable. However, its implementation may be a 'standard' array (one that actually holds the things it returns; e.g. Vec of integers) or a non-standard array that constructs the value in the index function (and so must return a value, not reference). What is the easiest way to do it? I can't use the Index trait as it [won't allow the latter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39113649/implementing-index-trait-to-return-a-value-that-is-not-a-reference). Currently it looks like I will have to wrap "standard Index"-es (e.g. Vec) with a custom Index trait that returns some Self::Output (and not &Self::Output). Sounds a bit too much for such a simple abstraction that I expect to be a pretty common need.

(About lifetimes; Be it a value or a reference, I intend to use the indexed value only during the indexer is lifetime)

Comment: Do you really need the `[]` notation? If not, you could invent your own `Indexable` trait, with a method as `.at(position)`, implement it for any type that implement the standard `Index` trait (by using a dereference), then implement it in a totally different way for the types that should generate the result instead of accessing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working off of the answer provided by prog-fh, here is my attempt at writing `Indexable` while avoiding the clone. This lets us directly return the references when `Index` is implemented, but also write implementations that return values that aren't references.

```rs
trait Indexable<'a, Idx>
where
    Idx: ?Sized,
{
    type Output<'b>: ?Sized
    where
        Self: 'b,
        'a: 'b;
    fn at<'b>(&'b self, idx: Idx) -> Self::Output<'b>
    where
        'a: 'b;
}

impl<'a, T: ?Sized, Idx, V> Indexable<'a, Idx> for T
where
    T: std::ops::Index<Idx, Output = V>,
    V: 'a,
{
    type Output<'b> = &'b V where Self: 'b, 'a: 'b;
    fn at<'b>(&'b self, idx: Idx) -> Self::Output<'b>
    where
        'a: 'b,
    {
        self.index(idx)
    }
}

struct Custom {}

impl Indexable<'static, usize> for Custom {
    type Output<'a> = usize;

    fn at<'a>(&'a self, idx: usize) -> Self::Output<'a>
    where
        'static: 'a,
    {
        idx * 2
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("testing on vector");
    let v = vec!["a".to_owned(), "b".to_owned(), "c".to_owned()];
    for i in 0..v.len() {
        println!("{} -> {}", i, *v.at(i));
    }

    println!("testing on custom");
    let c = Custom {};
    for i in 0..3 {
        println!("{} -> {}", i, c.at(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a question: When I use it in another trait (e.g. when returning an 'Indexable' from a method) what should I do with the lifetime? Is there a way by which I'll be able not to make the the new trait itself generic?

Comment: @BipoloTheGod your remark here is the main problem with this approach: the semantics changes from one implementation to another. If some implementations return values while other implementations return references, how could we use all of them in a common context? An algorithm dealing with values will be different from an algorithm dealing with references.

Comment: @prog-fh Well, indeed it would be different in the assembly, but theoretically it could be an implementation detail that is not presented in the trait itself (easy to imagine with c++)

Comment: @BipoloTheGod In C++ there is no distinction in the **syntax** when using a reference or a value (the `*` is implicit in C++, but this is a detail specific to this peculiar language; I don't know any other language like this, many others use references **everywhere** so that the disctinction does not even need to be made). In C or in Rust there is a difference between using or not the dereference (`*`) operation, because this is fundamentally different in the end, and even more with Rust where lifetime considerations come into play when using references.

Answer (score 3):

The `v[i]` operation is resolved as `*v.index(i)`; the `.index()` method comes from the `std::ops::Index` trait.
This `std::ops::Index` trait cannot be directly reused in your specific case in order to return a value, since it would change its semantics.

If we don't absolutely need the `[]` notation, then we can define our own `Indexable` trait dedicated to return a **value** at a given index.

All the types that already implement `std::ops::Index` can be made to automatically implement this new `Indexable` trait by cloning the referenced element in order to provide a **value** (not a reference).
Of course, this only applies to containers which elements implement `Clone`.

Any specific type relevant for your use case could then implement the `Indexable` in its own manner.

All of these different implementations should be usable in a common context, giving the ability to substitute an indexable with another one.

Please find below an example for all of this.

```rust
/// A specific trait to obtain a _value_ at a given index.
trait Indexable<Idx>
where
    Idx: ?Sized,
{
    type Output: ?Sized;
    fn value_at(
        &self,
        idx: Idx,
    ) -> Self::Output;
}

/// Generic implementation of Indexable for anything that implements Index.
///
/// The stored values must be clone-able in order to provide a value
/// without consuming the container.
impl<T: ?Sized, Idx, V> Indexable<Idx> for T
where
    T: std::ops::Index<Idx, Output = V>,
    V: Clone,
{
    type Output = V;

    fn value_at(
        &self,
        idx: Idx,
    ) -> Self::Output {
        self.index(idx).clone()
    }
}

/// A specific type for the purpose of the example
struct Dummy {}

/// This implementation of Indexable for this specific type
/// produces a value instead of accessing a previously stored one.
impl Indexable<usize> for Dummy {
    type Output = f64;

    fn value_at(
        &self,
        idx: usize,
    ) -> Self::Output {
        idx as f64 * 0.1
    }
}

fn work_with_indexable<Src: Indexable<usize, Output = f64>>(
    source: &Src,
    range: std::ops::Range<usize>,
) -> f64 {
    let mut accum = 0.0;
    for i in range {
        let v = source.value_at(i);
        println!("got {} at {}", v, i);
        accum += v;
    }
    accum
}

fn main() {
    println!("~~~~ generic implementation used on a vector ~~~~");
    let v = vec!["aa".to_owned(), "bb".to_owned(), "cc".to_owned()];
    for i in 0..v.len() {
        println!("vector at {} ~~> {}", i, v.value_at(i));
    }
    println!("~~~~ generic implementation used on an array ~~~~");
    let a = ["dd".to_owned(), "ee".to_owned(), "ff".to_owned()];
    for i in 0..a.len() {
        println!("array at {} ~~> {}", i, a.value_at(i));
    }
    println!("~~~~ specific implementation used on a dedicated type ~~~~");
    let d = Dummy {};
    for i in 0..3 {
        println!("dummy at {} ~~> {}", i, d.value_at(i));
    }
    println!("~~~~ using different implementations ~~~~");
    let r1 = work_with_indexable(&[1.2, 2.3, 3.4], 0..3);
    println!("slice: {}", r1);
    let r2 = work_with_indexable(&d, 0..3);
    println!("dummy: {}", r2);
}
/*
~~~~ generic implementation used on a vector ~~~~
vector at 0 ~~> aa
vector at 1 ~~> bb
vector at 2 ~~> cc
~~~~ generic implementation used on an array ~~~~
array at 0 ~~> dd
array at 1 ~~> ee
array at 2 ~~> ff
~~~~ specific implementation used on a dedicated type ~~~~
dummy at 0 ~~> 0
dummy at 1 ~~> 0.1
dummy at 2 ~~> 0.2
~~~~ using different implementations ~~~~
got 1.2 at 0
got 2.3 at 1
got 3.4 at 2
slice: 6.9
got 0 at 0
got 0.1 at 1
got 0.2 at 2
dummy: 0.30000000000000004
*/
```

Comment: It is a bad idea to define `Indexable` this way and always clone. Better to define it as GAT.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Sorry, I don't know how to do this. Maybe should you post an answer which shows the better way to handle this situation. I would be interested in seeing how it should be done; thanks.

Comment: I tried to construct an example but I was unable to overcome a restriction with lifetimes. I think it may be impossible to define it as GAT.

Comment: @prog-fh I gave it a shot. Let me know if there's something I'm missing or overlooked!