# How to borrow the T from a RefCell<T> as a reference?

Tags: generics, reference, rust, borrow-checker

Sometimes I have a `struct` containing a value which is wrapped in a `RefCell`, and I want to borrow the value, but I don't want to make the signature of the accessor function to depend on the internal implementation. To make it work, I need to return the reference as a `Ref<T>` instead of a `&T`.

For example, if this is my struct:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;

pub struct Outer<T> {
    inner: RefCell<T>,
}
```

I could write an accessor like this:

```
use std::cell::Ref;

impl<T> Outer<T> {
    fn get_inner_ref(&self) -> Ref<T> {
        self.inner.borrow()
    }
}
```

This works fine. I can use it like this:

```
fn main() {
    let outer = Outer { inner: RefCell::new(String::from("hi")) };
    let inner: &str = &outer.get_inner_ref();
    println!("inner value = {:?}", inner);
}
```

However, this exposes `Ref` as part of the public API, which would make it harder to change the internals later, without breaking backwards compatibility.

If I try change the signature to return an `&T` — which `&Ref<T>` can coerce to — then I get lifetime errors:

```
impl<T> Outer<T> {
    fn get_inner_ref(&self) -> &T {
        &self.inner.borrow()
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
error[E0597]: borrowed value does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:16:10
   |
16 |         &self.inner.borrow()
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ temporary value does not live long enough
17 |     }
   |     - temporary value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 15:5...
  --> src/main.rs:15:5
   |
15 | /     fn get_inner_ref(&self) -> &T {
16 | |         &self.inner.borrow()
17 | |     }
   | |_____^
```

There doesn't appear to be a way to fix that, because the error message is correct. The code is trying to take a reference to the `Ref<T>`, which only lasts as long as the function call. To make this work, I'd have to move out the `Ref<T>` itself by returning it — exactly like in the original code above — rather than making a new reference to it.

There is [an answer to How do I return a reference to something inside a RefCell without breaking encapsulation?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29401865/493729) which would technically solve this, but it is a more specialised case (to get only a part of the value in the `RefCell`) and the solution seems overly complex for this simpler situation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is exactly the purpose of `impl Trait`, which has been available in stable Rust [since version 1.26](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2018/05/10/Rust-1.26.html#impl-trait).

```
use std::ops::Deref;

impl<T> Outer<T> {
    fn get_inner_ref(&self) -> impl Deref<Target = T> + '_ {
        self.inner.borrow()
    }
}
```

The Rust compiler knows that the *actual* implementation is `Ref<T>` but lets you avoid having to write it explicitly, and callers of this function can only use functionality provided by the `Deref` trait.

As long as the actual value that you return is of a type that implements `Deref<Target = T>`, you are free to change that implementation later without breaking any code that uses it. For example, you could return `&T` or [one of several other reference types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html#implementors), including your own custom type, as in the [other linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29401865/493729).