# RefCell cannot return string slice from String; temporary value problem

Tags: rust

im trying to return a `&str` slice from a `String` which is behind a an `Rc<RefCell<>>`

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::{
    RefCell,
    Ref
};

struct Data {
    data: Rc<RefCell<String>>
}

impl Data {
    fn set(
        &mut self,
        data: String
    ) {
        *self.data.borrow_mut() = data;
    }

    // TODO: fix here
    fn get(&self) -> &str {
        self.data.borrow().as_str()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut data = Data {
        data: Rc::new(RefCell::new(String::new()))
    };
    data.set(String::from("how can i solve this?"));
    let d = data.get();
    println!("{}", d);
}
```

here's the compilation error

```bash
error[E0515]: cannot return reference to temporary value
  --> questions/refcell-data-inspection/src/main.rs:21:9
   |
21 |         self.data.borrow().as_str()
   |         ------------------^^^^^^^^^
   |         |
   |         returns a reference to data owned by the current function
   |         temporary value created here
```

well, i understand its a temporary value crated because `borrow` returns a guard, which will go out of scope.

how can i fix this in order to return a `&str` slice from that `String`?

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you said yourself "borrow guard" will be out of scope at the one of a function, so you cannot do that. Think of it that way. If you managed to return a reference into `String`, how would `RefCell` know that this reference exists and that it cannot give for example a mutable reference.

Only thing that you can do is to return that guard. This would mean, that you must change function's signature, but it will be as usable as a `&str` would be. So try this:

```rust
fn get(&self) -> Ref<'_, String> {
    self.data.borrow()
}
```

EDIT. You might want to also look at that question: [How to borrow the T from a RefCell<T> as a reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51349577/how-to-borrow-the-t-from-a-refcellt-as-a-reference)

Comment: I would add that if you want to return a reference to a part of the string instead of the whole string, you can use [`Ref::map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/cell/struct.Ref.html#method.map) like: `Ref::map (self.data.borrow(), |s| s.trim())` (`trim` is only an example of an operation returning a substring).