# Struggling with interior mutability

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, mutability

I have a data structure like this:

```
struct R {
    hmhs: HashMap<i64, HashSet<i64>>,
}

impl R {
    fn hs_for_hmhs(&mut self) -> &mut HashSet<i64> {
        if let None = self.hmhs.get(&0) {
            self.hmhs.insert(0, HashSet::new());
        }

        self.hmhs.get_mut(&0).unwrap()
    }

    fn iter_for_hmhs<'a>(&'a mut self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &'a i64> {
        self.hs_for_hmhs().iter()
    }

    fn insert_for_hmhs(&mut self, i: i64) -> bool {
        self.hs_for_hmhs().insert(i)
    }
}
```

This seems to work, but all the methods require a mutable
reference to `self` which is unfortunate. I tried to give
interior mutability a go:

```
struct S {
    hmhs: RefCell<HashMap<i64, HashSet<i64>>>,
}

impl S {
    fn hs_for_hmhs(&self) -> &HashSet<i64> {
        if let None = self.hmhs.borrow().get(&0) {
            self.hmhs.borrow_mut().insert(0, HashSet::new());
        }

        self.hmhs.borrow_mut().get_mut(&0).unwrap()
    }

    fn iter_for_hmhs(&mut self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &i64> {
        self.hs_for_hmhs().iter()
    }

    fn insert_for_hmhs(&mut self, i: i64) -> bool {
        self.hs_for_hmhs().insert(i)
    }
}
```

However, I constantly seem to hit problems. Mostly some variety of [How do I return a reference to something inside a RefCell without breaking encapsulation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29401626/how-do-i-return-a-reference-to-something-inside-a-refcell-without-breaking-encap)

I have tried lots of variants here, but I am missing something
fundamental in my understanding. Is there a way of achieving what I
want?

[Complete Code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0d189d366f6a4175ade027f8c0e77c5d&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015):

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::collections::{HashMap, HashSet};

struct R {
    hmhs: HashMap<i64, HashSet<i64>>,
}

impl R {
    fn hs_for_hmhs(&mut self) -> &mut HashSet<i64> {
        if let None = self.hmhs.get(&0) {
            self.hmhs.insert(0, HashSet::new());
        }

        self.hmhs.get_mut(&0).unwrap()
    }

    fn iter_for_hmhs<'a>(&'a mut self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &'a i64> {
        self.hs_for_hmhs().iter()
    }

    fn insert_for_hmhs(&mut self, i: i64) -> bool {
        self.hs_for_hmhs().insert(i)
    }
}

struct S {
    hmhs: RefCell<HashMap<i64, HashSet<i64>>>,
}

impl S {
    fn hs_for_hmhs(&self) -> &mut HashSet<i64> {
        if let None = self.hmhs.borrow().get(&0) {
            self.hmhs.borrow_mut().insert(0, HashSet::new());
        }

        self.hmhs.borrow_mut().get_mut(&0).unwrap()
    }

    fn iter_for_hmhs(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &i64> {
        self.hs_for_hmhs().iter()
    }

    fn insert_for_hmhs(&self, i: i64) -> bool {
        self.hs_for_hmhs().insert(i)
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

Compiler Message:

```
error[E0597]: borrowed value does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:36:9
   |
36 |         self.hmhs.borrow_mut().get_mut(&0).unwrap()
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ temporary value does not live long enough
37 |     }
   |     - temporary value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 31:5...
  --> src/main.rs:31:5
   |
31 | /     fn hs_for_hmhs(&self) -> &mut HashSet<i64> {
32 | |         if let None = self.hmhs.borrow().get(&0) {
33 | |             self.hmhs.borrow_mut().insert(0, HashSet::new());
34 | |         }
35 | |
36 | |         self.hmhs.borrow_mut().get_mut(&0).unwrap()
37 | |     }
   | |_____^
```

Comment: Why do you need to borrow it mutably? All of the methods return immutable references to its contents?

Comment: Which? The `HashMap` and the second `borrow_mut` call. I don't know. It complains more if I don't.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that `insert_for_hmhs` calls `insert`.

Comment: Oh, the `HashSet` -- yes, this part will fulfil the public interface of the struct. The HashMap is an implementation detail really.

Comment: This is a tricky problem, and I wonder if you should try a different approach. For example, [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=208ec1166fe2519d06b44194620b8912&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015) will get you half way - an abstracted smart pointer to the `HashSet`. But it's difficult to return an iterator to that.

Comment: Probably you'll need to create an iterator over a cloned `HashSet`

Comment: It's frustrating. The implementation is poking through. I could pre-instantiate the HashMap (actually possible in this case) I guess. But that's also unfortunate. It really should be lazy.

Comment: Is the key (0) in `hs_for_hmhs` fixed, or is this a simplification of the question and it may vary?

Comment: It's a simplification. Actually, the key is not a int, but values defined at compile time, so it's bounded. I could instantiate everything first. But there are 50-100 keys and in many cases, the HashSet values will be empty for many of these 50. So I'd rather not if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution -- extract the `HashMap` as a raw pointer. This in turn means that I can get to the `HashSet` without shenanigans including returning a iterator.

I'm happy enough with this as a solution. The unsafe code is small and contained and if I understand the reason why the compiler is complaining without unsafe, it cannot occur in this code, since neither the `HashMap` nor the `HashSet` are ever removed or replaced after construction.

That was a lot of effort.

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::collections::{HashMap, HashSet};

struct R {
    hmhs: HashMap<i64, HashSet<i64>>,
}

impl R {
    fn hs_for_hmhs(&mut self) -> &mut HashSet<i64> {
        if let None = self.hmhs.get(&0) {
            self.hmhs.insert(0, HashSet::new());
        }

        self.hmhs.get_mut(&0).unwrap()
    }

    fn iter_for_hmhs<'a>(&'a mut self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &'a i64> {
        self.hs_for_hmhs().iter()
    }

    fn insert_for_hmhs(&mut self, i: i64) -> bool {
        self.hs_for_hmhs().insert(i)
    }
}

struct S {
    hmhs: RefCell<HashMap<i64, HashSet<i64>>>,
}

impl S {
    fn hs_as_ptr(&self) -> *mut HashMap<i64, HashSet<i64>> {
        self.hmhs.borrow_mut().entry(0).or_insert(HashSet::new());
        self.hmhs.as_ptr()
    }

    fn mut_hs_for_hmhs(&mut self) -> &mut HashSet<i64> {
        unsafe { (*self.hs_as_ptr()).get_mut(&0).unwrap() }
    }
    fn hs_for_hmhs(&self) -> &HashSet<i64> {
        unsafe { (*self.hs_as_ptr()).get(&0).unwrap() }
    }

    fn iter_for_hmhs<'a>(&'a self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &'a i64> + 'a {
        self.hs_for_hmhs().iter()
    }

    fn insert_for_hmhs(&mut self, i: i64) -> bool {
        self.mut_hs_for_hmhs().insert(i)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut r = R {
        hmhs: HashMap::new(),
    };
    let mut s = S {
        hmhs: RefCell::new(HashMap::new()),
    };

    r.insert_for_hmhs(10);
    s.insert_for_hmhs(20);

    println!("r next: {:?}", r.iter_for_hmhs().next());
    println!("s next: {:?}", s.iter_for_hmhs().next());
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3ed1977bdd5f9f82d144fe128f618979&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015