# How do I enforce immutability for public views of reference-counted types with interior mutability?

Tags: rust

I am implementing a lookup data structure where the idea is to "hand out" references to some internal data, though this data is subject to change. I do not want any user outside my struct to change this data, only my internal function should be able to do this. Look at this example to have a better understanding:

```rust
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

struct Foo {
    some_data: Vec<u32>,
    handed_references: Vec<Rc<RefCell<usize>>>,
}

impl Foo {
    pub fn get_ref(&mut self) -> Rc<RefCell<usize>> {
        let rc = Rc::new(RefCell::new(10));
        self.handed_references.push(Rc::clone(&rc));
        rc
    }

    pub fn magic(&mut self) {
        for x in self.handed_references.iter() {
            *x.borrow_mut() = 15;
        }
    }
}
```

Right now, the values can be changed outside `Foo`. Is there a way to enforce immutability outside of `Foo`? Should I not use `RefCell`?

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [How do I return a reference to something inside a RefCell without breaking encapsulation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29401626/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: Thanks, the linked answer indeed solves the issue.