# "cannot return value referencing temporary value" and interior mutability in Rust

Tags: rust, ownership, interior-mutability, refcell

I have the following code in Rust:

```
pub struct RegExpFilter {
    ...
    regexp_data: RefCell<Option<RegexpData>>,
    ...
}

struct RegexpData {
    regexp: regex::Regex,
    string: String
}

...
    pub fn is_regexp_compiled(&self) -> bool {
        self.regexp_data.borrow().is_some()
    }

    pub fn compile_regexp(&self) -> RegexpData {
        ...
    }

    fn regexp(&self) -> &regex::Regex {
        if !self.is_regexp_compiled() { // lazy computation that mutates the struct
            self.regexp_data.replace(Some(self.compile_regexp()));
        }
        &self.regexp_data.borrow().as_ref().unwrap().regexp
    }
    
    pub fn matches(&self, location: &str) -> bool {
         self.regexp().find(location)
    }
```

regexp is calculated lazily, capturing `&mut self` i undesired so `RefCell` is used.

I'm getting the following message:

```
               &self.regexp_data.borrow().as_ref().unwrap().regexp
    |          ^-------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |          ||
    |          |temporary value created here
    |          returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

The compiler message seems to be clear: `Ref` is temporarily created by `borrow()` and returned outside. However i believe `Option` (`self.regexp_data`) is owned by `RefCell` which is owned by the struct itself, so it should be fine to use it internally (since the function is not `pub`).

I've also tried the following (and it fails with the same message)

```
    fn regexp(&self) -> impl Deref<Target = regex::Regex> + '_ {
        if !self.is_regexp_compiled() {
            self.regexp_data.replace(Some(self.compile_regexp()));
        }
        Ref::map(self.regexp_data.borrow(), |it| &it.unwrap().regexp)
    }
```

How can i solve it?

Comment: You can't get `&T` from a `RefCell<T>` without keeping the `Ref<T>` around, its how `RefCell` knows when `borrow()` and `borrow_mut()` are allowed. See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29401626/how-do-i-return-a-reference-to-something-inside-a-refcell-without-breaking-encap).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the `Ref::map` version by using `.as_ref()` to convert the `&Option<_>` to a `Option<&_>` in order to to unwrap as a reference:

```
fn regexp(&self) -> impl Deref<Target = regex::Regex> + '_ {
    if !self.is_regexp_compiled() {
        self.regexp_data.replace(Some(self.compile_regexp()));
    }
    Ref::map(self.regexp_data.borrow(), |it| &it.as_ref().unwrap().regexp)
                                              // ^^^^^^^^
}
```

---

In this scenario, I'd advocate for using `OnceCell` from the [once_cell](https://crates.io/crates/once_cell) crate:

```
use once_cell::sync::OnceCell;

pub struct RegexpData {
    regexp: regex::Regex,
    string: String,
}

pub struct RegExpFilter {
    regexp_data: OnceCell<RegexpData>,
}

impl RegExpFilter {
    pub fn compile_regexp(&self) -> RegexpData {
        unimplemented!()
    }

    fn regexp(&self) -> &regex::Regex {
        &self.regexp_data.get_or_init(|| self.compile_regexp()).regexp
    }
}
```

You can simply use `get_or_init` to get the same effect. `OnceCell` and `Lazy` (in the same crate) are very convenient for lazy-evaluation.

See it on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3f58aacb114d4aa64352dd7bad50129b).