# How to return an *optional* reference into RefCell contents

Tags: rust, refcell

I have a type that stores its data in a container behind a `Rc<RefCell<>>`, which is for the most part hidden from the public API. For example:

```
struct Value;

struct Container {
    storage: Rc<RefCell<HashMap<u32, Value>>>,
}

impl Container {
    fn insert(&mut self, key: u32, value: Value) {
        self.storage.borrow_mut().insert(key, value);
    }

    fn remove(&mut self, key: u32) -> Option<Value> {
        self.storage.borrow_mut().remove(&key)
    }

    // ...
}
```

However, peeking inside the container requires returning a `Ref`. That can be achieved using [`Ref::map()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Ref.html#method.map) - for example:

```
// peek value under key, panicking if not present
fn peek_assert(&self, key: u32) -> Ref<'_, Value> {
    Ref::map(self.storage.borrow(), |storage| storage.get(&key).unwrap())
}
```

However, I'd like to have a non-panicking version of `peek`, that would return `Option<Ref<'_, Value>>`. This is a problem because `Ref::map` requires that you return a reference to something that exists inside the `RefCell`, so even if I wanted to return `Ref<'_, Option<Value>>`, it wouldn't work because the option returned by `storage.get()` is ephemeral.

Trying to use `Ref::map` to create a `Ref` from a previously looked up key doesn't compile either:

```
// doesn't compile apparently the borrow checker doesn't understand that `v`
// won't outlive `_storage`.
fn peek(&self, key: u32) -> Option<Ref<'_, Value>> {
    let storage = self.storage.borrow();
    if let Some(v) = storage.get(&key) {
        Some(Ref::map(storage, |_storage| v))
    } else {
        None
    }
}
```

The approach that does work is to perform the lookup twice, but that's something I'd really like to avoid:

```
// works, but does lookup 2x
fn peek(&self, key: u32) -> Option<Ref<'_, Value>> {
    if self.storage.borrow().get(&key).is_some() {
        Some(Ref::map(self.storage.borrow(), |storage| {
            storage.get(&key).unwrap()
        }))
    } else {
        None
    }
}
```

Compilable example [in the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2e75b653a3e7c58df4fb8e8aad004740).

Related questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29401626/how-do-i-return-a-reference-to-something-inside-a-refcell-without-breaking-encap) assume that the inner reference is always available, so they don't have that issue.

I found [`Ref::filter_map()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Ref.html#method.filter_map) which would [solve this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4b8202d16ad1d35152cfc9ef4d2da2c6), but it's not yet available on stable, and it's unclear how far it is from stabilization. Barring other options, I would accept a solution that uses `unsafe` provided it is sound and relies on documented guarantees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a side effect to communicate whether the lookup succeeded, then return an arbitrary value from `Ref::map` if you don't have a successful value.

```rust
impl Container {
    // ...

    fn peek(&self, key: u32) -> Option<Ref<'_, Value>> {
        let storage = self.storage.borrow();
        if storage.is_empty() {
            // The trick below requires the map to be nonempty, but if it's
            // empty, then we don't need to do a lookup.
            return None;
        }

        // Find either the correct value or an arbitrary one, and use a mutable
        // side channel to remember which one it is.
        let mut failed = false;
        let ref_maybe_bogus: Ref<'_, Value> = Ref::map(storage, |storage| {
            storage.get(&key).unwrap_or_else(|| {
                // Report that the lookup failed.
                failed = true;
                // Return an arbitrary Value which will be ignored.
                // The is_empty() check above ensured that one will exist.
                storage.values().next().unwrap()
            })
        });
        
        // Return the ref only if it's due to a successful lookup.
        if failed {
            None
        } else {
            Some(ref_maybe_bogus)
        }
    }
}
```

Refinements:

- If the `Value` type can have constant instances, then you can return one of those instead of requiring the map to be nonempty; the method above is just the most general one that works for any definition of `Value`, and not the simplest. (This is possible since a `&'static Value` satisfies `Ref`'s requirements — the reference just needs to live long enough, not to actually point into the `RefCell`'s contents.)
- If the `Value` type can have a constant instance *that is distinct from any meaningful instance that would be found in the map* (a "sentinel value"), then you can check for that value in the final `if` instead of checking a separate boolean variable. However, this doesn't especially simplify the code; it's mostly useful if you have a sentinel you're using for other purposes anyway, or if you like a “pure functional” coding style which avoids side effects.

And of course, this is all moot if `Ref::filter_map` becomes stable.

Comment: This is really inventive, the kind of idea that is "obvious" once someone else points it out. The implementation is slightly more complicated than I'd like and requires the comments, but it's 100% safe and answers the question perfectly, so I'll accept it unless something even better comes up (which I doubt). In production I'll use a [different approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67247820/1600898), but this is a great safe solution for someone who needs a `peek()` that returns the actual reference, as described in the question.

Answer (score 4):

As of Rust 1.63, released on Aug 11 2022, [`Ref::filter_map()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.Ref.html#method.filter_map) is stable, so this simple solution is available:

```
pub fn peek(&self, key: u32) -> Option<Ref<'_, Value>> {
    Ref::filter_map(self.storage.borrow(), |storage| storage.get(&key)).ok()
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=94ab8dca6dca71bc49eac886ec783df8)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to come up with this:

```rust
fn peek<'a>(&'a self, key: u32) -> Option<Ref<'a, Value>> {
    // Safety: we perform a guarded borrow, then an unguarded one.
    // If the former is successful, so must be the latter.
    // Conceptually, they are the same borrow: we just take the pointer
    // from one and the dynamic lifetime guard from the other.
    unsafe {
        let s = self.storage.borrow();
        let u = self.storage.try_borrow_unguarded().unwrap();
        u.get(&key).map(|v| Ref::map(s, |_| &*(v as *const _)))
    }
}
```

I simply borrow the hashmap twice, then cast the lifetime away (by converting the reference into a pointer), then bring it back by re-borrowing the pointer’s referent. I un-elided the lifetime parameter just to be sure it doesn’t become too long.

I *think* it’s correct. I’d nevertheless keep looking forward to `filter_map` just to be sure.

---

Asker later came up with this variant, which I include here for the sake of avoiding link rot:

```rust
fn peek<'a>(&'a self, key: u32) -> Option<Ref<'a, Value>> {
    // Safety: we convert the reference obtained from the guarded borrow
    // into a pointer. Dropping the reference allows us to consume the
    // original borrow guard and turn it into a new one (with the same
    // lifetime) that refers to the value inside the hashmap.
    let s = self.storage.borrow();
    s.get(&key)
        .map(|v| v as *const _)
        .map(|v| Ref::map(s, |_| unsafe { &*v }))
}
```

Comment: That's quite elegant, thanks. But if we convert `v` to a pointer anyway, then maybe we don't need the second borrow at all, we can do everything with the first one, as long as we do it in two steps: 1) retrieve value from map and convert it to a pointer (thus disassociating it from the borrow), and then calling `Ref::map` whose closure converts the pointer back to reference: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8a199290db5edef6c8c917e4b8898844

Comment: I guess that works too. I tried to come up with a situation where it might break, but I couldn’t think of one. It seems no worse than my solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I ended up using until `Ref::filter_map()` is stabilized. It changes the signature of `peek()` from that specified in the question, so I won't be accepting this answer, but it might be useful for others who stumble upon this issue.

While `peek()` is a powerful primitive, its *usage* at call sites boils down to inspecting certain properties of the value and making decisions based on that. For that kind of usage, the caller doesn't need to retain the reference, it only needs temporary access to it to extract the properties it cares about. So we can let `peek` accept a closure that examines the value, and return its result:

```
fn peek<F: FnOnce(&Value) -> R, R>(&self, key: u32, examine: F) -> Option<R> {
    self.storage.borrow().get(&key).map(examine)
}
```

Where with `peek()` as originally specified one would write:

```
if let Some(event) = container.peek() {
    if event.time() >= deadline {
        container.remove_next();
    }
}
```

...with the `peek()` from this answer, one would instead write:

```
if let Some(event_time) = container.peek(|e| e.time()) {
    if event_time >= deadline {
        container.remove_next();
    }
}
```