# Obtain the a reference from a RefCelL<Option<T>> in Rust

Tags: rust

I am having a hard time getting a reference out of a `RefCell<Option<T>>`.

```rust
struct Consumer2<T> {
    tail: RefCell<Option<T>>,
}

impl<T> Consumer2<T> {
    fn read(&self) -> Ref<Option<&T>> {
        Ref::map(self.tail.borrow(), |v1| match v1 {
            None => &None,
            Some(v2) => &Some(v2),
        })
    }
}
```

The compiler point out to a lifetime issue.

```
For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0495`.
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for pattern due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/lib.rs:28:18
   |
28 |             Some(v2) => &Some(v2),
   |                  ^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the body at 26:38...
  --> src/lib.rs:26:38
   |
26 |           Ref::map(self.tail.borrow(), |v1| match v1 {
   |  ______________________________________^
27 | |             None => &None,
28 | |             Some(v2) => &Some(v2),
29 | |         })
   | |_________^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/lib.rs:28:18
   |
28 |             Some(v2) => &Some(v2),
   |                  ^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the anonymous lifetime defined on the method body at 25:13...
  --> src/lib.rs:25:13
   |
25 |     fn read(&self) -> Ref<Option<&T>> {
   |             ^^^^^
note: ...so that the expression is assignable
  --> src/lib.rs:26:9
   |
26 | /         Ref::map(self.tail.borrow(), |v1| match v1 {
27 | |             None => &None,
28 | |             Some(v2) => &Some(v2),
29 | |         })
   | |__________^
   = note: expected `Ref<'_, Option<&T>>`
              found `Ref<'_, Option<&T>>
```

I am not sure if I understand the issue itself.

Comment: The return type `Ref<Option<&T>>` looks like it contains an unnecessary borrow. Since `Ref<T>` already implies `T` being borrowed (and allows extracting `&T` with lifetime tied to the lifetime of the `Ref`), maybe you really want `Ref<Option<T>>` (in which case you could just return `self.tail.borrow()`), or even `Option<Ref<T>>`, in which case you might find answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67243000/1600898) useful.

Comment: Indeed, it would work. Unfortunately, my needs is a little more complex than that. But it would work.

Comment: Can you expand your example to better represent your needs? Perhaps a better solution is possible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68158383/obtain-a-reference-from-a-refcelloptionrct-in-rust

Comment: You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68152483/edit) this question, you don't need to ask a new one.

Comment: Given the new configuration you provided, you cannot return a `Ref<Option<T>>` because an `Option<T>` just doesn't exist in the `RefCell`. You could return an `Option<Ref<T>>` (which is probably more useful to begin with), refer to the question linked in my first comments for ideas how to do so.

Comment: The question was not edited, because the use of the Rc completely changed the semantic of the question. Those are 2 completely different questions. Even if they look similar.

Comment: @user4815162342 actually an `Option<Ref<T>>` would be even more useful.

Comment: The questions are different, but the original question doesn't make much sense as asked because it would be trivially answered by returning `self.tail.borrow()`, which obviously doesn't resolve your actual issue. In that case it's better to edit the question to provide details than to leave the original impractical question and ask a new one, without providing context or compiler error messages, etc.

Answer (score 0):

When you add lifetime annotations, then you get something like that:

```rust
impl<T> Consumer2<T> {
    fn read(&'s self) -> Ref<Option<&'s T>> {
        Ref::map(self.tail.borrow(), |v1: &'a Option<T>| match v1 {
            None => &None,
            Some(v2: &'a T) => &Some(v2),
        })
    }
}
```

The inferred lifetime for return is the lifetime of the self because of the lifetime elision rules. From [Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html#lifetime-elision):

> The second rule is if there is exactly one input lifetime parameter, that lifetime is assigned to all output lifetime parameters: fn foo<'a>(x: &'a i32) -> &'a i32.

> The third rule is if there are multiple input lifetime parameters, but one of them is &self or &mut self because this is a method, the lifetime of self is assigned to all output lifetime parameters.

So rust expects that return value will have lifetime of `self`.

But in closure passed to `Ref::map` it gets another lifetime `'a`, because of the first elision rule:

> (...) each parameter that is a reference gets its own lifetime parameter

Rust cannot guarantee that borrowed object will outlive the closure, so it cannot guarantee that `'s` and `'a` lifetimes are equal or `'a` outlives the `'s` which is required by return type inferred lifetime.

EDIT: As @Siscia pointed out this doesn't compile

In short: try to give explicit lifetime to your parameters:

```rust
impl<T> Consumer2<T> {
    fn read(&'s self) -> Ref<Option<&'s T>> {
        Ref::map(self.tail.borrow(), |v1: &'s Option<T>| match v1 {
            None => &None,
            Some(v2) => &Some(v2),
        })
    }
}
```

But you probably will have other problems, because returning references from closure is nearly never a good idea.

But this works:

```rust
impl<T> Consumer2<T> {
    fn read(&self) -> Ref<Option<T>> {
        Ref::map(self.tail.borrow(), |v1| match v1 {
            None => &None,
            some => &some,
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Does returning `&Some(v2)` ever actually compile? It looks like it returns a reference to a locally constructed option, and as such shouldn't be allowed regardless of lifetime annotations.

Comment: No, the code provided does not compile as example in this answer does not compile.

Comment: @user4815162342 I cannot check it right now, but Option<T> is `Copy` when T: Copy, and shared references are `Copy` implicitly, so it can work. But still it's not a good idea to do it like that.

Comment: Note that in your final code `some` is already `&Option<T>`, so `some` works as well as `&some` (in fact `&some` gets auto-dereffed to `some` by the compiler). And such a `match` is equivalent to just returning `self.tail.borrow()` which, as discussed in comments to the question, is probably not what the OP wants.