# Obtain a reference from a RefCell<Option<Rc<T>>> in Rust

Tags: rust

I am having problem getting a reference out of a RefCell<Option<Rc>>.

Any suggestion?

```
struct Node<T> {
    value: T
}

struct Consumer3<T> {
    tail: RefCell<Option<Rc<Node<T>>>>,
}

impl<T> Consumer3<T> {
    fn read<'s>(&'s self) -> Ref<Option<T>> {
        Ref::map(self.tail.borrow(), |f| {
            f.map(|s| {
                let v = s.as_ref();
                v.value
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Gives:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:15:13
   |
15 | /             f.map(|s| {
16 | |                 let v = s.as_ref();
17 | |                 v.value
18 | |             })
   | |______________^ expected reference, found enum `Option`
   |
   = note: expected reference `&_`
                   found enum `Option<T>`
help: consider borrowing here
   |
15 |             &f.map(|s| {
16 |                 let v = s.as_ref();
17 |                 v.value
18 |             })
   |

error: aborting due to previous error
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5337ef020b44ca2ff77975bf317d30c3)

Comment: @Jmb please re-open the question, the use of the Rc completely change the semantinc of what we are trying to achieve. From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68152483/obtain-the-a-reference-from-a-refcelloptiont-in-rust

Comment: I've voted to reopen the question because I suspect the answers are different. The duplicate answer says "yes you can do that, here's how" but I believe the answer to *this* question is either "you cannot" or maybe "you can but with a different mechanism"

Comment: @kmdreko The questions are indeeed different, but the original question doesn't make much sense as asked because it would be trivially answered by returning `self.tail.borrow()`, which obviously doesn't resolve the OP's issue. In that case I believe it's much better to edit the question to provide details than to leave the original impractical question and ask a new one, which the OP did without providing any context, compiler error messages, etc.

Comment: If the original question is left unedited, then this question is likely a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67243000/1600898).

Comment: An `Rc` inside a `RefCell` is different from an `RefCell` inside an `Rc`.

Comment: Returning `Ref<Option<T>>` is simply impossible, as it requires there be an `Option<T>` in existence somewhere reachable from the `RefCell` (which there isn't).

Comment: Hence, it will be impossible also to return also an `Option<Ref<T>>` ?

Comment: No, [that's possible](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=46318ed01ad1d4406268de593cc48315).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mapping from one `Ref` to another requires that the target already exist in memory somewhere.  So you can't get a `Ref<Option<T>>` from a `RefCell<Option<Rc<Node<T>>>>`, because there's no `Option<T>` anywhere in memory.

However, if the `Option` is `Some`, then there will be a `T` in memory from which you can obtain a `Ref<T>`; if the `Option` is `None`, obviously you can't.  So returning `Option<Ref<T>>` may be a viable alternative for you:

```rust
use std::{cell::{Ref, RefCell}, rc::Rc};

struct Node<T> {
    value: T
}

struct Consumer3<T> {
    tail: RefCell<Option<Rc<Node<T>>>>,
}

impl<T> Consumer3<T> {
    fn read(&self) -> Option<Ref<T>> {
        let tail = self.tail.borrow();
        
        if tail.is_some() {
            Some(Ref::map(tail, |tail| {
                let node = tail.as_deref().unwrap();
                &node.value
            }))
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=489a430763c5ca1f0f4d5c025801a1b6).

Comment: Thanks a lot! This code was extremelly tricky! I appreciate your help!

Comment: And, for those coming here with Rust >= 1.63.0, I think this can be done with [`Ref::filter_map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Ref.html#method.filter_map). [Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b2832c909efddb761566d34079584656)