# Iterator for a Linked List in Rust

Tags: rust

I am new to Rust and am trying to learn it. I've read a bunch of different material and believe I have the gist of important concepts like the borrow checker, references, lifetimes, smart pointers, etc. But I am having a difficult time trying to understand more abstruse concepts like `RefCell`, `Mutexes`, `Pin`, etc., to be able to actually code with these data structures. It's all very abstract to me.

1. Where can I learn more about items like these to actually code with them?
2. I have a particular question about implementing the `Iterator` trait to iterate references inside a `RefCell` for a `LinkedList` data structure I have coded and can't seem to get to work because it causes issues with temporary borrows and the like, and I haven't got the slightest clue how to approach these problems to work around said issues.

Nonetheless, here is my code:

```
use std::{
    cell::{Ref, RefCell},
    rc::Rc,
};

type LinkNodePtr<T> = Rc<RefCell<LinkNode<T>>>;

pub struct LinkNode<T> {
    data: T,
    next: Option<LinkNodePtr<T>>,
    prev: Option<LinkNodePtr<T>>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct LinkedList<T> {
    head: Option<LinkNodePtr<T>>,
    tail: Option<LinkNodePtr<T>>,
    len: usize,
}

impl<'a, T> LinkedList<T> {
    pub fn new(data: T) -> Self {
        let link_node_ptr = Rc::new(RefCell::new(LinkNode {
            data,
            next: None,
            prev: None,
        }));

        LinkedList {
            head: Some(Rc::clone(&link_node_ptr)),
            tail: Some(Rc::clone(&link_node_ptr)),
            len: 1,
        }
    }

    pub fn add_to_head(&mut self, data: T) {
        let link_node_ptr = Rc::new(RefCell::new(LinkNode {
            data,
            next: self.head.take(),
            prev: None,
        }));

        self.head = Some(Rc::clone(&link_node_ptr));

        let link_node = link_node_ptr.borrow_mut();
        if let Some(ref link_node_ptr_next) = link_node.next {
            let mut link_node_next = (*link_node_ptr_next).borrow_mut();
            link_node_next.prev = Some(Rc::clone(&link_node_ptr));
        }

        self.len += 1;
    }

    pub fn add_to_tail(&mut self, data: T) {
        let link_node_ptr = Rc::new(RefCell::new(LinkNode {
            data,
            next: None,
            prev: self.tail.take(),
        }));

        self.tail = Some(Rc::clone(&link_node_ptr));

        let link_node = link_node_ptr.borrow();
        if let Some(ref link_node_ptr_prev) = link_node.prev {
            let mut link_node_prev = (*link_node_ptr_prev).borrow_mut();
            link_node_prev.next = Some(Rc::clone(&link_node_ptr));
        }

        self.len += 1;
    }

    pub fn iter(&'a self) -> LinkedListIter<'a, T> {
        let current = if let Some(ref head) = self.head {
            Some(head.borrow())
        } else {
            None
        };
        LinkedListIter { current }
    }
}

pub struct LinkedListIter<'a, T> {
    current: Option<Ref<'a, LinkNode<T>>>,
}

impl<'a, T> Iterator for LinkedListIter<'a, T> {
    type Item = Ref<'a, T>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if let Some(link_node) = self.current.take() {
            self.current = if let Some(ref link_node_ptr_next) = link_node.next {
                let link_node_next = (*link_node_ptr_next).borrow();
                Some(link_node_next)
            } else {
                None
            };
            Some(Ref::map(link_node, |x| &x.data))
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

impl<'a, T> std::fmt::Debug for LinkNode<T>
where
    T: std::fmt::Debug,
{
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        f.debug_struct("LinkNode")
            .field("data", &self.data)
            .field("next", &self.next)
            .finish()
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn it_works() {
        let mut ll = LinkedList::new(1);
        ll.add_to_tail(2);
        ll.add_to_tail(3);
        ll.add_to_tail(4);
        ll.add_to_head(5);
        ll.add_to_head(6);

        for x in ll.iter() {
            println!("{}", x);
        }

        println!("{:?}", ll);
    }
}
```

```
error[E0505]: cannot move out of `link_node` because it is borrowed
  --> src\linked_list.rs:97:27
   |
86 | impl<'a, T> Iterator for LinkedListIter<'a, T> {
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
91 |             self.current = if let Some(ref link_node_ptr_next) = link_node.next {
   |                                                                  --------- borrow of `link_node` occurs here
92 |                 let link_node_next = (*link_node_ptr_next).borrow();
   |                                      ------------------------------ argument requires that `link_node` is borrowed for `'a`
...
97 |             Some(Ref::map(link_node, |x| &x.data))
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^ move out of `link_node` occurs here
```

Comment: 1: off-topic but check out [entirely to many lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/) / 
2: You forgot to add your attempt and where you got stuck with it.

Comment: I added it. I'm not sure it would help because I was effectively just shooting in the wind without really knowing what I was trying to do. I understand the error that the borrow doesn't live long enough because it goes out of scope, but I don't understand why that prevents the reference to the internal data it points to.

Comment: It helps in so far as requests for code are off-topic, [SO isn't a code writing service](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/442760). An actual question you have about some code you wrote is definitely on topic though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return a reference to something inside a RefCell without breaking encapsulation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29401626/how-do-i-return-a-reference-to-something-inside-a-refcell-without-breaking-encap)

Comment: I saw that but I don't really understand that example. I'm really confused with the borrow checker here. All I need is a reference to the "data" (of type T) property of the LinkNode<T> for each iteration. However, dynamically borrowing the contents of the RefCell to gain access to Ref<LinkNode<T>> and trying to return a reference to the "data" property within it gives me that value does not live long enough error which makes sense for the Ref. But I don't understand how I CAN make the ref to "data" live long enough. Iterating a data structure always presupposes the existence of data within it.

Comment: tl;dr you can't, you should return the `Ref` instead. By using `RefCell` you opted out of static borrow checking and into 'dynamic borrow checking'. The compiler can't determine the lifetimes anymore. To track the lifetime there is the `Ref<T>` structure wich behaves just like a regular reference `&` in most cases, but it tells the `RefCell` when it is safe to borrow it's contents again when it goes out of scope. You can only return the `Ref<T>` not a reference to it because the reference becomes invalid as soon as `Ref<T>` goes out of scope.

Comment: Ok, I changed my implementation and added lifetime parameters which I don't really follow. I understand references within structs must live for lifetimes that are greater than or equal to the lifetime of the containing object, but I don't really "get" templated lifetime parameters as of now. Regardless, now I am running into a different error which I don't understand.

Comment: @cafce25 You can't return a `Ref<T>` because it carries the lifetime of its accompanying `RefCell`, and it's [important to return items from an iterator that reference the iterator itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30422177/how-do-i-write-an-iterator-that-returns-references-to-itself). The only reason it works with other data structures is the fact that their lifetime can be forwarded to the item produced by the iterator. But as a linked list is almost impossible to implement with lifetimes and require refcounters, that won't work.

Comment: The only way I could think of making this work is by using singly-linked-lists and `Box`. `Box` is compatible with lifetimes. But `Rc` isn't. But again, all of this is layed out in the 'too-many-lists' article.

Comment: Your problem is pretty much **exactly** layed out in this page: https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/fourth-iteration.html#iter

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid it won't work with lifetime annotations, because the lifetime of every node is different. That's exactly why linked lists in Rust are so hard, and much of that is layed out in ["Learn Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists"](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/), which is an excellent read and almost mandatory if you want to deal with recursive data structures like linked lists.

To fix your problem, instead of holding `Ref` values to the next item, hold the `Rc` itself. That's what `Rc` is for.

That said, it's currently impossible to return a value from an iterator that borrows the iterator itself. That makes it impossible to return a `Ref` from an iterator, as a `Ref` must always be connected to a `RefCell` via a lifetime, and the `RefCell` would have to be stored inside the iterator.

So right now, I'm afraid I have to tell you that your approach isn't possible without `unsafe` (to my knowledge).

The 'Entirely too many linked lists' article seems to agree, it has an entire chapter about `Rc<RefCell<T>>` based doubly-linked lists and how they are incompatible with iterators.

**TLDR:** Don't try to write linked lists in Rust. It's a concept that simply isn't compatible with Rusts ownership rules. If you want to do it anyway, read  ["Learn Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists"](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/) first.